# A javascript function that complete another function sent as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, parameters

In the following javascript function window.setInterval(function,milliseconds) I can do the following:

```
var myvarible = function(){alert('Popup');};
window.setInterval(myvarible,5000);
```

now every 5 seconds my webpage will alert the message 'popup'

How can I make my own function do the parameter myvarible, as see above? This is what I am trying below, but it does not work.

```
text = "";

var myvarible = function() {
   for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      text += cars[i] + "<br>"; 
      }
   }

function howLong(the_function){
  var starting_time = new Date().getMilliseconds();

  the_function //do the function here

  var finishing_time = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  var difference = finishing_time-starting_time;
  document.write(difference);
}

howLong(myVarible);  //call my howLong function
```

I hope you understand me, I have tried to make myself as clear as possible and I am new to javascript so please try to keep the answers as simple as possible.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make 3 corrections.

1.) calling `howLong(myVarible);`  should be `howLong(myvarible);` because you are defining function as `myvarible`

2.)You have to call the function add `()` in function `howLong`

```
`the_function() //do the function here`
```

3.) define `cars`.

This worked for me

```
<script>
    text = "";
    var cars = [1,2,3];

var myVarible = function() {
   for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      text += cars[i] + "<br>"; 
      }
   }

function howLong(the_function){
  var starting_time = new Date().getMilliseconds();

  the_function() //do the function here

  var finishing_time = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  var difference = finishing_time-starting_time;
  document.write(difference);
}

howLong(myVarible);  //call my howLong function
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `()` after the variable to call it as a function:

```
the_function(); // do the function here
```